# How to call a datepicker in a Magento 2 system.xml file

Tags: magento2

I need to add date type in system.xml file with the datepicker option in Magento 2. Can anyone tell me how to call a datepicker?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi You can use 2 options for this case:

1 `<frontend_model>Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\Datetime</frontend_model>`

2 `<source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Date\Short</source_model>`

See more info from **`vendor/magento/magento-config`**